# Scraping issue with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a simple script that will tell me when the next episode of x show will be released.

here is what I have so far:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.tv.com/shows/game-of-thrones/episodes/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

puts doc.at_css('h1').text
airdate =  doc.at_css('.highlight_date span , h1').text
date = /\W/.match(airdate)
puts date
```

when i run this all it returns is:
Game of thrones

The css selector I use there gives the line airdate is /xx/xx/xx, however I only want to the date so thats why I have used the /\W/ although I could be completely wrong here.

So basically I want it to just print the show title and the date of the next episode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below :-

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.tv.com/shows/game-of-thrones/episodes/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

# under season4 currently 7 episodes present, which may change later.
doc.css('#season-4-eps > li').size # => 7

# collect season4 episodes and then their dates and titles
doc.css('#season-4-eps > li').collect { |node| [node.css('.title').text,node.css('.date').text] }
# => [["Mockingbird", "5/18/14"],
#     ["The Laws of God and Men", "5/11/14"],
#     ["First of His Name", "5/4/14"],
#     ["Oathkeeper", "4/27/14"],
#     ["Breaker of Chains", "4/20/14"],
#     ["The Lion and the Rose", "4/13/14"],
#     ["Two Swords", "4/6/14"]]
```

Looking at the webpage again, I can see, that it always open with latest season's data. Thus the above code can be modified as below :-

```
# how many sessions are present
latest_session = doc.css(".filters > li[data-season]").size # => 4

# collect season4 episodes and then their dates and titles
doc.css("#season-#{latest_session}-eps > li").collect do |node| 
  p [node.css('.title').text,node.css('.date').text] 
end
# >> ["The Mountain and the Viper", "6/1/14"]
# >> ["Mockingbird", "5/18/14"]
# >> ["The Laws of God and Men", "5/11/14"]
# >> ["First of His Name", "5/4/14"]
# >> ["Oathkeeper", "4/27/14"]
# >> ["Breaker of Chains", "4/20/14"]
# >> ["The Lion and the Rose", "4/13/14"]
# >> ["Two Swords", "4/6/14"]
```

---

As per the comment, it seems OP may interested to get the data out from **NEXT EPISODE** box of the webpage. Here is a way to do the same :

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.tv.com/shows/game-of-thrones/episodes/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

hash = {}
doc.css('div[class ~= next_episode] div.highlight_info').tap do |node|
  hash['date'] = node.css('p.highlight_date > span').text[/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/]
  hash['title'] = node.css('div.highlight_name > a').text
end

hash # => {"date"=>"5/18/2014", "title"=>"Mockingbird"}
```

Worth to read [`tap{|x|...} → obj`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-tap)

> **Yields** `x` to the block, and then returns x. The primary purpose of this method is to “tap into” a method chain, in order to perform operations on intermediate results within the chain.

and [`str[regexp] → new_str or nil`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Also read [`CSS selectors`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) to understand how the *selectors* are with the method `#css`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

However how would i change this so that it only collects the newest episode, indefinitely (as in it will automatically go from season 4 to 5 without having to change code).

Comment: I don't know how the above code is working but you could use .next_episode class to get latest episode related HTMl and inside it you will relevant information.

Comment: @HarryLucas Okay. Data on the page is being loaded through *AJAX*, which is not supproted by *Nokogiri*. To do this, you can use *selenium-webdriver* to execute *AJAX* call, and then *nokogiri* to prase the html page and get the data out from there.

Comment: @amitamb this is working a bit better. what I have is this now



`puts doc.at_css('h1').text
airdate =  doc.at_css('.next_episode').text
puts airdate.scan(/\d+/)`

but that gives me each individual number on seperate lines (as in 5 next line 18 next line 2014) how would i get them on the one line?

Comment: @HarryLucas What's the problem with this code, with mine ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I think with your one it was grabbing the data from within the season 4 box, whereas all I want is the "next episode box" at the top of the page. I dont know I could be wrong, im very new to this and don't fully understand what you meant by your previous question

Comment: @HarryLucas Do you want latest episodes data always, or any episodes data at all times?

Comment: @ArupRakshit yes that is basically it. I had to add `.next_episode` to  `doc.css('.highlight_info').tap` as it was getting the info from the previous episode as well (and that date => should be 5/18/2014, not 5/11/2014). Now it comes up with this `date=>'nil' title=>'Mockingbird'` so the title is right just not the date. Thanks for all your help though!